# “Launching Delegate” Stuck at 27% - Eclipse Neon

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-neon

When I try to launch my app it keeps getting stuck at “Launching Delegate”, more specifically at 27%.
I've tried every possible solution I could find, but still no luck.

What I've tried until now:
Start Eclipse Window -> AVD Manager -> Start an emulator -> Run the project

Create new AVD -> Start an emulator -> Run the project

Create new AVD -> Exit eclipse -> Open eclipse and emulator -> Run the project

Also tried:
Reinstalling eclipse, clearing project and
Exiting adb.exe (from task manager) before opening eclipse.

None worked, please help this error is driving me crazy for tens of hours now.

Probably worth mentioning that everytime I want to run the project I'm getting this 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmKYv.jpg),
I have the right AVD set in "run configurations", AVD is opened and when says "...is now stopped" I belive that AVD it should close then but it still remains opened.

Comment: Exit Eclipse, get AndroidStudio. Eclipse is kind of "deprecated" for android development. Don't waste another 10 minutes on it.

Comment: Thank you for opening my eyes, I should've done that sooner.